# Loading Images (Java)

Tags: java, image, optimization, awt, tiles

I'm making a simple game in java, and I have levels based on tiles. I'm not sure how to go about this.

So I have a question... Is it easier for java to:

- Load four 50 by 50 images (in a 100 by 100 screen). 
  Or
- Load sixteen 25 by 25 images (in a 100 by 100 screen)

Also, how would I go about optimizing this?

I've done many tests with 50 by 50 tiles, and when I cover the entire screen, the game lags. (from 60fps to like 30fps).
The screen is 750 by 1200 for a total of 360 blocks. Is there anyway to make this run faster or should I try not to put too many tiles? I'm using buffered images for my tiles.

Comment: I don't think it will a lot of difference.  You have to remember though, the overhead (in terms of additional data, like color models, etc) of a lot of small images may be greater then that of a small number of large images.  Instead of trying to paint all the titles (or the visible area) on each repaint, try painting them to a `BufferedImage` instead and only updating those parts you need to on each cycle.

Comment: Do you load the images each time you repaint? It takes time to load images from files. You should store the images in objects (`BufferedImage`) such that you only have to load them once.